# $x\cos x+\sin x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n-1},a_{n},a_{n+1},...$ be the positive roots of the equation

$x\cos x+\sin x=0$

in ascending order.

Then prove that

$2a_{n+1}<a_{n+2}+a_{n}$

My Attempt:

The given equation reduces to

$\tan x=-x$

Then I tried to draw graph of $y=\tan x$ and $y=-x$ all i could deduce was that $\frac{\pi}{2}<a_{n+1}-a_{n}<\pi$ but beyond that nothing could be established

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+tan+x+and+-x+from+-100+to+100

Comment: This I did but there should be an analytical way to do it.

Comment: You could try a proof by induction. But you'll need a function that gives the location of the nth zero. BTW, the inequality says that zeroes get closer to each other with increasing $n$: $a_{n+1} - a_n > a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} \Rightarrow  2a_{n+1}<a_{n+2}+a_{n}$

Comment: @Χpẘ In fact, the opposite seems to be happening here - as $x$ increases, the distance between roots is monotonically increasing toward $\pi$, with first term $2.0288...$

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: @Χpẘ odd. Perhaps my graphing software was to blame? I'll check it with different software later.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen that's weird. That's not what I see when I graph it. I used desmos.com. There are two pairs zeroes at $\approx 4.493, 7.725, 73.814, 76.956$. The difference between the first pair is $3.232$ and the second is $3.142$, so the differences are definitely decreasing. Which is good because that's what the OP needs to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=x+\tan x$ with domain $(0,\pi/2)$. This function is strictly increasing and strictly concave up. Note that $a_n=n\pi-b_n$ where $b_n=f^{-1}(n\pi)$. Now $f^{-1}$ is concave down, so Jensen's inequality implies
$$
  \frac{b_n+b_{n+2}}2<b_{n+1},
$$
whence the result.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

The solutions $a_n$ are such that $$ a_n= (2 n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} +\epsilon_n$$ where $\epsilon_n$ is "obviously" smaller and smaller.

Considering that we look for the zero of function $$f(x)=x\cos (x)+\sin( x)$$ we could use a single iteration of Newton method starting using $x_0=(2 n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and get $$a_n\approx x_1=(2 n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2}{(2   n+1)\pi }$$ which would lead to $$a_{n+2}+a_n-2a_{n+1}=\frac{16}{\pi  \left(8 n^3+36 n^2+46 n+15\right)}$$